# Titanium alloy list only 2 items display

Tags: listview, titanium, titanium-alloy

I am attempting to create a list view in Titanium using an alloy model. I have 1 view nested within a view. The idea is that it will create 3 lines, one will be horizontal. It displays the first two, and not the third (I can change the order, it will still just display whatever the first two lines are.

listTemplate.xml:

```
<Templates>
  <ItemTemplate name="sampleTemplate">
    <View class="templateSection">
      <Label class="listItem" id="firstItem" bindId="firstItem" />
      <Label class="listItem" id="secondItem" bindId="secondItem" />
      <View class="listItem" id="dueDate">
        <Label class="listItem" id="dateLabel" text="Date Due: " />
        <Label class="listItem" id="dueDate" bindId="taskDueDate" />
      </View>
    </View>
  </ItemTemplate>
</Templates>
```

listTemplate.tss

```
".listItem": {
    top: "1dp",
    left: "0"
}
".templateSection":{
    layout: "vertical",
    textAlign: Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_LEFT,
    left: "4dp"
}
"#dueDate": {
    layout: "horizontal"
}
```

Again, this works fine for the first two labels, but the nested view does not display. If I move #secondItem below the #dueDate view, then that view shows, and #secondItem does not. I've experimented with height, but it doesn't seem to fix it.

Of note, I also tried to create 3 views stacked, to add labels to #firstItem and #secondItem the way that there is a hard coded label, then a dynamic item in the nested view. When I did that, only 1 of the three items displayed (the first one).